# C2DM to GCM code Migration

Tags: android, migration, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I have migrated my code for push notifications from C2DM to GCM. The only change I have made on client side is replacing the email account passed in the sender parameter of the registration intent with the project ID. The server side changes have been done too.

However, I experience a delay in receiving push while using GCM. The delay is like for 1 - 2 mins. I did not experience the same delay while using C2DM.

Please help!! Is this problem cause of GCM, or am I missing something.

Comment: Migrated too recently, not sure about the delays because C2DM have them too from time to time. 
Changed only notify ID on client side.

Answer (score 0):

I've set up GCM and pushes are almost instant. Couple things to check is that your server is sending it without a delay. And also that you are not spamming it, i noticed that after a certain amount of pushes in a small time period, and Google will start delaying pushes..

Other than that the only issue could be the GCM service and/also your phone. Make sure that your phone's radio is open at all times and you are using a stock OS. See if the problem is still happening in couple of hours so (in case there's a problem at the GCM servers)